# How to catch inherited type of Exception

Tags: java, exception

```
    +--------+     +-----+
    | a.b.EA |<----|s.EC |
    +--------+     +-----+
     ^      ^
     |      |
  +------+ +------+
  |x.y.EC| |r.l.EC|
  +------+ +------+


pacakge r.l;
public interface X{
    void f() throws a.b.EA;
}

pacakge r.l;
public class M implements X{
    public void f() throws a.b.EA {
        throw new r.l.EC();
    }
}


package x.y;
import r.l.M;
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        new M().f();
    }catch(EC e){ (**)
    }
}
```

And the question is: How to catch **exactly** instance of `EC` (because `EC` says something about cause- `EC` is like `Invalid URL`).

`M.f()` throws `r.l.EC()` and I can catch `r.l.EC`. But, other implementation `X` can throw, for example `s.EC`, and so on. So, I cannot be prepared. What to do in that situation.

Comment: multiple catch blocks

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't know in advance the exact type of exception other implementations of your interface may throw, you can try to catch your specific exception, and then the more general exception:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        new M().f();
    }
    catch(EC e) {
        // specific error handling
    }
    catch(EA e) {
        // more general error handling
    }
}
```

Comment: but if I would like to catch `r.l.EC`? Or `another.one.EC` or `yet.another.one.EC`. The external library can inherit `EA`, and how to catch it?

Comment: @asdas You can only catch those other exception classes if you know about them, have access to them and expect exceptions of these classes to be thrown by that method.